# samsung c48x scanner not working

Tags: drivers, scanner

the issue is common but I haven't been able to solve it yet.
Ubuntu 16.04.
Printer c48x working properly.
Its scanner is not working, neither with Simple Scan not with XSane.
I remember there is a Samsung repository but I can't find it
GA

Comment: Look at `http://bchemnet.com/suldr/`

Comment: thanks I had done it and I found I am supposed to use the "version 1.00.36 (driver2)". Downloaded it and clicked on "install scanner.sh" . This is what pops up

Comment: #!/bin/sh

SCRIPTS_DIR=$(dirname "$0")/noarch

# load 'scripting' run-time support utility functions
. "${SCRIPTS_DIR}/scripting_utils"
script_log_init $(basename "$0" ".sh")

# load 'package' run-time support utility functions
. "${SCRIPTS_DIR}/package_utils"
environment_init $(basename "$0" ".sh")

if sh "$SCRIPTS_DIR/pre_install.sh" "$@" ; then
 sh "$SCRIPTS_DIR/package_install.sh" "scanner-meta"
 sh "$SCRIPTS_DIR/post_install.sh" "$@"
fi

Comment: I don't understand what I should do with this script. Paste in in terminal?

Comment: I have the same issue: Samsung c48x worked fine with Ubuntu 14.04, after upgrade to 16.04 only the printer part continued to work, the scanner was not found anymore, neither with simple-scan,  sane nor xsane.

Comment: When declaring the ip address of the scanner in /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf
 (ax explained here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SANE/Scanner-specific_problems#Samsung)  but xsane now crashed with the following error when scanning:  "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00
"

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and first experimented with KDE. After installing suld-driver2-1.00.39, my Samsung C480W worked out of the box with Simple Scanner. I then changed back to Gnome for some good reason; now the printer is detected and I can print, but `scanimage -L` won't find the printer, nor will Simple Scanner, and the gnome printer setup dialog doesn't show anything suldr-ish.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *exactly* suld-driver2-1.00.36 -- .39 does not work and segfaults when trying to scan.
Installing the .deb does not require manually running any scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Even though OP is on Ubuntu, i think it might be good-to-know: on arch, the drivers from the AUR do work like charm:

```bsh
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/samsung-unified-driver.git
cd samsung-unified-driver
makepkg -si
```

after running this, the device is listed (and `simple-scan` does work):

```
scanimage -L                                                  
device `smfp:net;192.168.0.168' is a Samsung C48x Series on 192.168.0.168 Scanner
```

Note: this will install `v1.00.39-4`, no segfault for me (on `5.4.39-1-MANJARO`)